# Is there a json schema file for eos that defines accounts, keys, transactions, blocks, etc

Tags: eosio-code, database

Is there a json schema file or data-model for eos that defines accounts, keys, transactions, blocks, etc...

Comment: I have been working on an extensive schema for EOSIO and it will be complete in approximately 2 weeks. Will post as answer when repository is public.